# ¿Como puedo dar un salto de linea al escribir un archivo en Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

He estado teniendo problemas con realizar un salto de línea. Mando llamar mis datos y en mi base de datos no existe un salto de línea. muestro un poco de mi código.
De esta forma muestro mis datos.

```
var txtCheckpoint = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCheckpoint);
txtCheckpoint.Text = modelErrorCode.CheckPoints;
```

Comment: \n no funciona?

Comment: No, no funciona. :( @L.Ronquillo

Comment: Puedes hacerlo colocando `\n`: txtCheckpoint.Text = modelErrorCode.CheckPoints + "\n";

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas insertar un salto de linea simplemente usa :

```
Environment.NewLine
```

Esto lo tendrías que concatenar valor que deseas tenga al final un salto de linea, por ejemplo:

```
      string valor = "Nombre: Maria"  + Environment.NewLine + "Apellido: Bernal";
      Console.WriteLine(valor);
```

el valor de salida sería:

```
Nombre: Maria 
Apellido: Bernal
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo agrega 
 para cada linea que desees agregar.

En xaml:

```
En <label Text="Linea 1 &#10; Linea 2"...
```

En cs:

```
mivariable.Text = "linea 1" + \r\n + "linea 2";
```

Comment: NO se agrego la primera opcion. 
<Label Text="linea 1 &#10; Linea 2 &#10;..."

Comment: A mi me funciono sin problema: "\r\n". Ejemplo: "Texto 1" + "\r\n" + "Texto 2". No se por que lo votaron mal.

Answer (score -1):

Un poco tarde, pero lo unico que tienes que hacer es escribir  
 ejemplo:

```
Text="First line &#10; Second line"
```

Comment: Text="First line &#10; Second line"

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por colaborar, tratamos de que las respuestas, sean explicativas, la tuya casi es solo código, eso hace que se considere de baja calidad (independientemente de si es correcta), por otro lado, parece que haces una corrección de la misma en los comentarios, puedes editar tu respuesta, y corregir las veces que sea necesario, te recomiendo que mires [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.

Comment: Puedes [edit] la respuesta todo lo que haga falta hasta que consideres que está completa. En los comentarios sólo va eso, comentarios. En esta oportunidad, te ayudo con el formato